# resize AVPlayerItem container view based on aspect ratio from video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, aspect-ratio

I have a container UIView called `videoView`. I add a AVPLayerLayer to that view. I do not know how to resize the `videoView` to be of the same proportions as the avplayer layer. Using `videoGravity` does not have the desired effect.

```
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:path];

_videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];

[_avplayerLayer setPlayer:_videoPlayer];
[_avplayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[_avplayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[_avplayerLayer setFrame:_videoView.bounds];
[_videoView.layer addSublayer:_avplayerLayer];
```

I am using autolayout, and my layout would accommodate a change in the height of _videoView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

videoGravity will not change the frame of the view, instead it fills the current frame with the video.

i think you should inspect each video's [resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364942/2066810) before playing it and adjust `videoView`'s height constraint (which should be an ivar and constrained to `videoView`'s width) [multiplier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/multiplier). `videoView` width should be constrained to the screen width.

Comment: thanks! coupled with this answer I got it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34643565/1392515